# Subsetting data set in SAS by referencing an external text file

Tags: sas, subset, data-manipulation

I am working with a data set from the FDA that contains data on reactions to pharmaceutical drugs.  I am trying to subset the data by the names of drugs.  I have an external text file with the drug names that I am interested in.  I want to create a subset of the data comprised of my drugs of interest.  My external text file is titled SSRIFULL.txt and the variable name is DRUGNAME.  I tried many things that were blatantly wrong

i.e.

DATA SSRIFULL2;

----   SET SSRIFULL;

---- If Drugname ~= "P:\APPRENTICESHIP\SSRI_LIST.txt" then delete;

Run;

and I cannot find any literature on the matter directly.  Should I look more into the topics on truncover or maybe proc sql?  The text file contains a list of ~20 drugs. I am open to some type of inline code as well but for some reason SAS does not like this...

DATA SSRIFULL2;

---SET SSRIFULL;

------IF (AGE >19) OR (AGE = .) Then Delete;

------If (DRUGNAME ~= 'clomipramine' OR 'fluvoxamine' or 'Paxil' or 'paroxetine' or 
'Prozac'

------or 'fluoxetine' or 'Seroquel' or 'Wellbutrin' or 'bupropion' or 'Zoloft' or 'sertraline'

------OR 'Zyban') Then Delete;

RUN;

As is probably evident, I do not have a lot of experience with SAS I am just trying to get this data set useable for analysis at this point.
Thank you for any help in advance

Comment: Does your external file containing drug names have each drug on one lines (mean the file has 20 or so lines in it)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should consult the SAS documentation to learn the necessary syntax. Your second attempt was pretty close, but this is correct:

```
DATA SSRIFULL2;
 SET SSRIFULL;
 IF (AGE >19) OR (AGE = .) Then Delete;
 If DRUGNAME in ('clomipramine' 'fluvoxamine' 'Paxil' 'paroxetine' 'Prozac' 'fluoxetine' 'Seroquel'  'Wellbutrin' 'bupropion' 'Zoloft' 'sertraline' 'Zyban') then delete;
RUN;
```

Note that names stored in the variable `drugname` will be case sensitive, so if, say, the variable is 'paxil' and you try to match on 'Paxil' that won't work. You could use the `lowcase` function to deal with this.

To implement something like your first attempt, you'll have to read the file in to a SAS dataset and then use that to do the matching in a second step:

```
data ssri_list;
 length drugname $50.;
 infile 'P:\APPRENTICESHIP\SSRI_LIST.txt';
 input drugname$;
run;

proc sql;
 create table ssrifull2 as
  select * from ssrifull where 0<=age<19 and drugname not in
   (select drugname from ssri_list);
quit;
```

or something like that.

Comment: Thank you for the support.  Your fix worked and thank you for the tip on the lowcase function as this data is a hot mess.

Comment: +1 for the second answer; I'd modify it to use either the `UPCASE` or `LOWCASE` functions on both references to `drugname` to make it even better!